# How to setup Array of custom classes in Unity c#

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a class and declare an array of that class.

Here is the C# code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class gameControl : MonoBehaviour {
public GameMaster[] allTile;

public class GameMaster {
    public GameObject block;

    public GameMaster (GameObject thisBlock){
        block = thisBlock;
    }
}

void Start () {
    GameObject[] allBlocks = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");

    for (int i = 0; i < allBlocks.Length; i++){
        Debug.Log (allBlocks[i].name);
        GameMaster thisGameObj = new GameMaster(allBlocks[i]);
        allTile[i] = new GameMaster(thisGameObj);
    }
}

}
```

When I ran the script I encounter following error message:

> Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'gameControl.GameMaster.GameMaster(UnityEngine.GameObject)' has some invalid arguments (CS1502) (Assembly-CSharp)

I believe it should be way I declare the GameMaster array or accessing it in the loop. Wonder if anyone can point out my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

The `GameMaster` class has a constructor that takes as an argument an object of type `GameObject`. In the following line of codes:

```
GameMaster thisGameObj = new GameMaster(allBlocks[i]);
allTile[i] = new GameMaster(thisGameObj);
```

Initially you create a `GameMaster` object and then you pass this object to the GameMaster's constructor, which is not correct.

Comment: Thanks!! Think I found the solution to this and uses List instead of Array which works so much better :)